# How to quit the app from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to do a very simple thing, show alert with only 1 button, if clicked I want the dialog to close and than the app to quit\finish()

currently I'm getting on the device the generic alert:

***The application  has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again***

In the LogCat I get: ***Unable to pause activity***

Here is the log:

```
01-03 14:49:00.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.SprintTwo/com.SprintTwo.SprintTwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3162)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1874)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at com.phonegap.DroidGap.onPause(DroidGap.java:736)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap.onPause(WLDroidGap.java:163)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3782)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1190)
01-03 14:49:00.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
```

Here is my code:

```
buttonClickListener = new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                        }

AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dlg.setTitle(title);
    dlg.setMessage(message);
    dlg.setCancelable(false);
    dlg.setPositiveButton(buttonText, buttonClickListener);
    dlg.create();
    dlg.show();
```

Comment: buttonClickListener is null when you use it in dlg.setPositiveButton ... so when you click on positive button you gettin' NPE

Comment: Is `at com.phonegap.DroidGap.onPause(DroidGap.java:736)`from your code? Sure you don't have anything strange there?

Comment: Can you write us what you have at DroidGap.java at line 736? Also i am curious what is at WLDroidGap.java at line 163. there must be some issues there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try System.exit(0) instead of finish()

Comment: This is not the proper way to close Android app but for my very specific case it worked... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you cannot finish activity from Pause mode.

Idea is to handle it with flag.
Write the Exit code in Resume() method with the flag check. Enable the flag in Dialog.

Something like (below code is dummy),

```
boolean APP_EXIT_FLAG = false;
Resume(){

if(APP_EXIT_FLAG)
finish();

}
```

And your alert dialog code,

```
buttonClickListener = new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                           APP_EXIT_FLAG = true;
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dlg.setTitle(title);
    dlg.setMessage(message);
    dlg.setCancelable(false);
    dlg.setPositiveButton(buttonText, buttonClickListener);
    dlg.create();
    dlg.show();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: From where should I call Resume() ?

Comment: if your app is in paused mode it will call resume (lifecycle method) automatically

Answer (score -1):

try if work

```
private void ConfirmAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("CLOSE");
    builder.setMessage("Do You Want to Close the Application").setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            onYesClick();

        }


    }).setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
            onNoClick();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
private void onYesClick() {
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);

    ActivityName.this.finish();



}private void onNoClick() {


}
```